# Django, create list of objects which can be mass deleted, edited etc

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I can't seem to find much information on building editable list views.

So for example I'd like to create a list of users, each juxtaposed with checkbox, for the purpose another user could go through and mass delete users or alternatively edit some attributes of each user.

What's the best way to go about this, or what terminology do I need to search to find out how to do this?  Ideally, I'd like a class based views solution (ListView?) but a FBV would also work.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is formset. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/

If you want to delete bunch of users you could:

1) Create Userform, which has one additional boolean field - delete

2) Change the form, that in save method, if delete equals True, you delete the object

3) Create formset, which uses previouscly created form:

```
UserFormSet = modelformset_factory(User, form=PreviouslyCreatedUserForm)
```

4) If in view formset cleans without errors call formset.save()

5) Give user some feedback.

Perhaps doing it in form save method is not ok, in that case you can also loop through the forms in view like. You would have to set some kind of parameter then though, to find out  if form/object is marked for deletion.

```
for form in formset:
  if form.delete = True:
    obj = form.save(commit = False)
    obj.delete()
```

Anyway, formsets are very powerful tool, look into the subject and i am sure it will come up with different ways to use it.

Comment: [`modelformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelformset_factory) has a `can_delete` argument. You don't have to add a boolean field manually.

Comment: yeah right, that's correct. Did not think about it :).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, came up with a nice solution using ModelFormSetView from django extra views which supports can_delete.  Just when i thought django couldn't get any sweeter..